# How to display the value of key in dictionary in jinja2 template?

Tags: django, python-3.x

> I want to display the value of a particular key of dictionary in django template.

```
dict1 = {'Device.Bridging.': '0', 'Device.': '0', 'Device.XMPP.SupportedServerConnectAlgorithms': '0'}
```

For ex: I want to display the value of key "Device.XMPP.SupportedServerConnectAlgorithms"

---

This is how I am trying to access the value.

```
<div>
<p>{{dict1.Device.XMPP.SupportedServerConnectAlgorithms}}</p>
</div>
```

But the above code is giving null value.

and

```
<div>
<p>{{dict1["Device.XMPP.SupportedServerConnectAlgorithms"]}}</p>
</div>


Exception Type:     TemplateSyntaxError
Exception Value:    

Could not parse the remainder: '["Device.XMPP.SupportedServerConnectAlgorithms"]' from 'pvals["Device.XMPP.SupportedServerConnectAlgorithms"]'
```

Comment: You are not using Jinja2. You are using Django template language.

Comment: I think you can find solution here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11801061/django-template-how-to-show-dict-whose-key-has-a-dot-in-it-dkey-name

Comment: @DanielRoseman i have updated it, thankyou

Comment: @SergeyPugach I tried the solution provided in the link you shared, but I am getting the following error.
Could not parse the remainder: '["Device.XMPP.SupportedServerConnectAlgorithms"]' from 'pvals["Device.XMPP.SupportedServerConnectAlgorithms"]'

Comment: Then you didn't follow Sergey's link at all.

Comment: @DanielRoseman I checked it twice, I am still not able to figure out what is causing the error.

Comment: So please show your updated code. Did you create that filter? How are you using it in the template?

Comment: from django import template
register = template.Library()

@register.filter
def get_key(value, arg):
    return value.get(arg, None)

And I am trying to access using this command in template,
{{ pvals|get_key:"Device.XMPP.SupportedServerConnectAlgorithms" }}

Comment: There is no possible way that that code could give you the error you claim.

Answer (score 0):

You should send a context dict to a template

**views.py**:

```
from django.shortcuts import render

def index(request):
    dict1 = {
        'test_var': 'test0',
    }

    return render(request, 'test_template.html', dict1)
```

**templates/test_template.html:**

```
<div>
    <p>
        {{ test_var }}
    </p>
</div>
```

**# OUTPUT:**

```
test0
```

---

EDIT:
You cannot use `.` in your variables. (Try using underscore)